# Running software on amazon workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace, amazon-workspaces

I am planning to use Amazon Workspace, to run a communication software which is restricted in a country where I am about to visit in few days, so what I was thinking is to use amazon workspace, but I was wondering if anyone can guide me if its safe to keep running any communication software with personal credentials on Amazon Workspace?

I have confusion if I run Workspace, will I get the same desktop each time? or if I log out from client it will end the existing desktop, and once I sign in again it will get me a new desktop with everything same as previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon WorkSpaces provisions a virtual server that is always "yours". Just keep it running and connect to it whenever you want to use it. It will continue exactly how you left-off, such as mid-sentence in a word processor.

Clients are available for Windows, Mac, iOS, Android and even via Web Browser so it should be easy to connect.

The only potential problem is if the country has blocked access to the AWS IP address range, which might happen if they want to block people from using VPN services.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a standard procedure for you to be cautious whenever you are using internet connection away from the trusted connection points. However, it is quite secure to keep running your communication software on AWS Workspaces. Their security protocol is advanced. You should also change your credentials on a regular basis.

You will always get the same desktop anytime you login and so that shouldn't be a problem.

Alternatively, you can checkout [V2 Cloud's WorkSpaces](https://www.v2cloud.com/cloud-workspaces/) they have an enterprise-grade security strategy to protect both your data and credential. They use multi-factor authentication to ensure that even if your credentials are stolen, the theif can't sign into your WOrkPSaces.

About having access to the same desktop, their desktop is very consistent and you will always have access to the same desktop. They will not only host your communication software, they will render to you via your web browser so you don't have to install any client application like in AWS WorkSpaces.

I hope that helps.